# Bootstrap grid system jsfiddle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm trying to try bootstrap's grid system on jsfiddle but I'm unable.

[See it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hotvic/fC9vQ/)

I've taken bootstrap doc example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     ...
</div>
```

items get stacked instead of horizontally aligned.

Comment: Check out your markup on http://bootply.com/130116 -- Bootply includes Bootstrap's JS/CSS for you and has a wider preview pane.

Comment: @Baghoo thank you, the Bootply is a good alternative to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> items get stacked instead of horizontally aligned.

because that is the [intended result when the viewport is resized](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) - in your case, using `col-md` classes, the columns would start stacking in a viewport that is less than 992px. Look at [your same fiddle in fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/hotvic/fC9vQ/embedded/result/), or just resize the window horizontally.